# The dynamic call of a static function fails - "Class "SomeClassName" not found"

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to call a model dynamically via a variable. However, it fails ( `"Class "SomeClassName" not found"`). Here is my code:

```php
use App\Models\SomeClassName;
use App\Models\SomeClassName1;

class SomeClassName {
    public function store(string $someClassName, array $requestData): array
    {
        $model = $someClassName::with('relation')->findOrFail($requestData['item_id']);
        // ...
    }
}

$someClassName->store('className', []);
```

Comment: then `$className` isn't a FQCN to an existing class ....

Comment: @lagbox I have changed the names to make it more understandable / abstract. So no competition with other classes. Thank you for asking.

Comment: that wasn't a question ... `$className` is not a FQCN to an existing class ... why are you expecting said class to exist?

Comment: @lagbox Ok. I didn't know that. Then I will change that. I was not aware of it. Thanks for the hint.